@GeneratedValue doesn't support with not Id column after upgrading to springboot 3.2.4
I was upgrading springboot 3.1 to 3.2.4 which uses hibernate 6.4.4.Final.
I am getting the below error while building the mvn project-
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [/JpaConfiguration.class]: Property 'id2' is annotated @GeneratedValue but is not part of an identifier
entity -
  @Id
    @Min(100000000)
    @Max(9999999999L)
    private Long id1;

 

    @Column(name = "id2")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id2;

Just want to know is there any workaround for the problem without using custom generator

It never worked or was supported but Hibernate now explicitly checks this and throws an exception. Just remove the @GeneratedValue as it never worked anyway.

Remove @GeneratedValue from id2: You can simply remove the @GeneratedValue annotation from id2.
@Column(name = "id2")
private Long id2;

Change the strategy for id2: If you intend id2 to have generated values but not as a primary key, you can use a different strategy such as GenerationType.AUTO. However, this might not be suitable for all scenarios and could lead to potential issues with uniqueness.
@Column(name = "id2")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id2;

Choose the option that best fits your requirements and the semantics of your entity model.

@GeneratedValue isn't supported (never was) on non @Id fields.
